# Binning data based on each row in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bin, binning

```
a = train_images.reshape(60000, 28, 28)
print(np.shape(a))
a_view = a.reshape(60000, 7, 4, 7, 4)
print(np.shape(a_view))
binned_out = []
for x in range(len(a)) :
   bin_v = a_view[x].mean(axis=3).mean(axis=1)
   binned_out.append(bin_v)
```

In the above code, is there any other way to change the for loop to decrease the execution time and getting the binned data for all the elements in numpy array.

My train_images shape is (60000, 784)

Comment: Use `axis` param : `a_view.mean(axis=(2,4))`.

Comment: Thank you, It works and saved a lot of time